# I have a row, but somehow my button and textarea align underneath each other instead of next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
function getEblockRow() {
    let eBlockRow = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
    }));
    console.log(eBlockRow);
    return eBlockRow;
}

function getEblock() {
    let eBlock = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-3'
    }));
    return eBlock;
}
```

how I append:

```
$(function () {
    $(getEblock().appendTo(getEblockRow()));
    $(getEblock().append(getTextArea(), submitButton())).appendTo('#form');
});
```

My console shows that I do have a row, but somehow the button and the texarea are put underneath each other, I have pretty much no css, so I can't have done something wrong there. What am I missing out on?

Comment: Have you tried to create it in pure HTML and see the result?

Comment: Yes, in HTML I have no difficulties making it, but when I tru to create these things with javascript (practicing) I end up with the stuff underneath each other (that explains my newbie question)

Comment: where is submitButton() function?

Comment: In my javascript, but in a seperate function...

Comment: `textarea` and `button` is inline like. But, because of the `col-md-3` they are not in the same line but flowing to the next line. If you could try it using it without `col-md-3` for once then it might work. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/wEQMzW)**.

The problem is in the way you're appending the divs to each other, check :

```
function getEblockRow() {
    let eBlockRow = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
    }));
    console.log(eBlockRow);
    return eBlockRow;
}

function getEblock() {
    let eBlock = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-3'
    }));
    return eBlock;
}

$(function () {
    var container = getEblockRow();
    var block = getEblock().append('<textarea></textarea>', '<button class="btn">Submit</button>')

    container.append(block);
    container.append(block.clone(true));
    container.append(block.clone(true));

    $('#form').append(container);
});
```

Comment: a quick question if you don't mind, why aren't you using the dollar sign to be able to append everything else? like this: $(getEblock().appendTo(getEblockRow()));

Comment: Since when we call `getEblock()` function every time it will create a new instance, in your code, when you call it the second time in the second line you will lose the first div `row` and it will return a new instance of `col-md-3` that not connected with `row` and this new instance will be appended to form... that why I store it in `block` so I could use the same instance when I need it...